# Mailboxer: creating link to new conversation on a product page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I am working on a marketplace.
I have a page with all the products.

I want to create a link on each of this product, to allow user to send message to the seller, creating a new conversation.

I am thinking about creating a link with that:

```
<%= link_to "Contactar", new_conversation_path %>
```

But can i put in this link the recipient directly ?

If yes, what should i change in the conversation_controller ?

```
def new
  recipients = Product.where(user: params[:user_id])
end

def create
  receipt = current_user.send_message(recipient, params[:body], params[:subject])
  redirect_to conversation_path(receipt.conversation)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But can i put in this link the recipient directly ?

Yes! You can pass the individual recipient id directly in the link like below

```
<%= link_to "Contactar", new_conversation_path(recipient_id: @your_recipient.id %>
```

And access the *recipient's id* with `params[:recipient_id]` in the *new* method.

Comment: Thanks but how can i get the user_id here as i'm on the product page?
In my DB, on the product table i have user_id.

should it look like that: 
<%= link_to "Contactar", new_conversation_path(recipient_id: @service.id %>

service = Service.find(params[:user_id]) 

?Thanks in advance

Comment: @Tomas It should be *recipient's id*. In your case *seller's id*.

Comment: Here what i've written:
<%= link_to "Contac", new_conversation_path(recipient_id: @seller) %>


      def new@seller = Service.find(params[:user_id])
  end

But i get an error "could'nt find service with id

Comment: Actually, i'm getting close:
I have written now:
<%= link_to "Contact", new_conversation_path(recipient_id: service.user.id) %>      on the service page,

So when i click on the button, the correct user id is present in the url, but i'm getting an error on the page still.

Comment: now i can access the new conversation page (the url show: conversations/new?recipient_id=7),
I can wrrite the message and send it, but when i go on the "conversations" page of the user "7" i can't see this conversation

My code in conversation controller:
 def new
    @ recipient = params[:recipient_id]
  end

  def create
    receipt = current_user.send_message(@recipient, params[:body], params[:subject])
    redirect_to conversation_path(receipt.conversation)
  end

Comment: @Tomas It is better to post another question rather stretching this topic. Also as my answer solved the problem of this question, you should mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146087/discussion-between-tomas-and-pavan).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i finally written:

On my product listing

```
<%= link_to "Contact", new_conversation_path(recipient_id: service.user.id) %>
```

In the conversations_controller:

```
def new

@recipient = params[:recipient_id]
end

def create
receipt = current_user.send_message(@recipient, params[:body],     params[:subject])
redirect_to conversation_path(receipt.conversation)
end
```

So now on the conversation new page, the url show: /conversations/new?recipient_id=

thanks @Pavan